# Intellij IDEA - Evaluate expression with stream API cause error

Tags: java, debugging, intellij-idea

I'm struggling with evaluation expression that contains some Stream API methods.
Example:

```
sample.reads.stream().filter(s -> s.l.length() < 10)
```

This doesn't work as well:

```
sample.reads.stream().filter(s -> s.l.length() < 10).collect(Collectors.toList())
```

gives:

[image]

However, `sample.reads.stream().count()` or `sample.reads.stream().toArray()` works fine as well as any other expression(and if I put stream API call into code it also works fine)

Config:
Java:
jdk1.8.0_144

Idea:
IntelliJ IDEA 2017.3.1 (Community Edition)
Build #IC-173.3942.27, built on December 11, 2017
JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1024-b8 amd64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Windows 10 10.0

**UPDATE**

Sorry, for confusion. Even terminal commands don't work. I showed this example because I found that examption is thrown on filter method, not on collect. If I add .collect() I'll see the same error

**UPDATE 2**
I don't think it's something with classes. Even this gives me the same error:

```
IntStream.range(0, 100).filter(i -> i%2 == 0).toArray()
```

Comment: You should give what is the type of sample, and the type of individual elements of sample.reads it is clear by the error that you miss some dependencies in the classpath

Comment: @Hamdi Douss They are all my classes that are located in 'edu.gsu.molel' package. I don't think that it is the problem since 'sample.reads.stream().toArray()' works fine

Comment: Please include the object schema on which you're trying to evaluate the lambda

Comment: Are they in the same project or in a different project ?

Comment: This seems to work just fine for me.  I note that if I attempt to debug something in a running application that *doesn't* have the right classes imported, it will fail to do so with a similar error, but I'm usually given the option to "import" it in the debug window.  Do you see any errors suggesting that you don't have access to the `Collectors` class?

Comment: @HamdiDouss in the same project. I added one more example with only standard Java classes and it doesn't work even in that way

Comment: @Makoto no, I don't see anything like this. In code it works fine, but not in debugger

Comment: @Vyacheslav what "same" error do you get? Is it the same packages that do not exist? Is the compilation error in the same line? (Intstream?)

Comment: Yeah, I'm pretty sure this is a bug in IntelliJ. it would be nice if they would fix it!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a bit of a guess, but the problem seems to be **a classpath related** problem. Due to this you get the message that specific packages cannot be found.

I do not think this is due to terminal or non terminal stream operations. Even non terminal operations can be evaluated in IDEA without errors. See this:

[image]

I strongly suggest to check the Run/Debug configuration in IDEA and check which classpath is being used for this application. Open the following dialog and check what is in the "Use classpath of module" field:

[image]

A wrong value might have sneaked in there.

Comment: Yes, you are right. For some reason, I had two modules in Project Structure - with my project name and 'main'. I removed 'main' and reran debug and it works! Thanks

Comment: This was happening for me because I was debugging a Gradle JavaExec type task and IntelliJ was not set to "Delegate IDE build actions to Gradle."  Checking that box in the settings resolved the classpath issue for me.

Comment: In my case, I get the "package does not exist" if i use stream api, but normal list iterator works fine.

Answer (score -2):

Look at the JAVA Stream API document here -

> Stream operations are divided into intermediate and terminal
>   operations, and are combined to form stream pipelines. A stream
>   pipeline consists of a source (such as a Collection, an array, a
>   generator function, or an I/O channel); followed by zero or more
>   intermediate operations such as Stream.filter or Stream.map; and a
>   terminal operation such as Stream.forEach or Stream.reduce.
>
> Intermediate operations return a new stream. They are always lazy;
>   executing an intermediate operation such as filter() does not actually
>   perform any filtering, but instead creates a new stream that, when
>   traversed, contains the elements of the initial stream that match the
>   given predicate. Traversal of the pipeline source does not begin until
>   the terminal operation of the pipeline is executed.
>
> Terminal operations, such as Stream.forEach or IntStream.sum, may
>   traverse the stream to produce a result or a side-effect. After the
>   terminal operation is performed, the stream pipeline is considered
>   consumed, and can no longer be used; if you need to traverse the same
>   data source again, you must return to the data source to get a new
>   stream.

As it says, filter is a intermediate operation and not the terminal. In order to execute or complete the stream pipeline, you must have to have terminal operation. And hence, Intellij is giving the compilation error.

In case of `sample.reads.stream().count()` or `sample.reads.stream().toArray()`, `count()` & `toArray()` - both are terminal operations and hence it works fine.

To solve your problem, do something like this in Intellij expression evaluator -

```
sample.reads.stream().filter(s -> s.l.length() < 10).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Here, `collect()` is the terminal operation & it will put the result in the list as mentioned by `Collectors.toList()`.

Comment: Please, see my update on the question. The terminal operation doesn't help, still the same error.

Comment: @VyacheslavTsivina So you are saying the same expression works in the code? And not in Intellij expression evaluator?

Comment: Yes. And I added example in the question with pure Java classes that doesn't work either

Comment: this is a debugger compilation error (IntelliJ specific), how does it relate with "unterminated" stream?